# Do I need multithread in my program?

Tags: arduino

My project is about fabricating a spin coater. Basically a machine that uses centrifugal for to cover a substrate  with micro thickness. Anyway, for this project, it requires me to key in time and speed of the motor uses to spin the substrate. Then read the rpm of motor, and the restart again for new session. My problem now is, how do I run the motor whilst the rpm is read using a sensor.   Let me go through the process of this machine,

Step 1: set speed of motor (using servo value of 103-180) and timing of motor in second( how long the motor need to spin).

In this step, there are 3 stages of speed and time setting. I need to key in the speed and timing of this stages using a keypad.

Step 2: spinning of the motor and rpm measurement reading

For this step, the  value of speed and time is turn into integer. This allow the motor to spin according to the time given. At the same time, as the motor spinning, the rpm measurement also start, reading the rpm of motor and display on the LCD screen.

Step 3:  motor stop and repeat step 1

Here is my problem, how do I make the motor to spin whilst rpm reading is taken?  Can i do it in single thread or multithread( hopefully won 't in multithread, still a beginner in arduino)

Comment: There is no threading on an Arduino.

Answer (score 3):

Arduino doesn't have threads.  Threads are usually a feature of the operating system.  With Arduino, you don't have an operating system in the classic sense. 
 Your code, including the libraries it uses, runs directly on the hardware.

The system is set up so that your `loop` function will be called over and over again.  The usual way of doing multiple things at once (like controlling the speed of the motor and reading a sensor and updating a display) is to do a little bit of each task during the loop.  In pseudocode it might look like this:

```
void loop() {
  int rpm = read_rpm_from_sensor();
  adjust_motor_timing(rpm, target_rpm);
  display_speed(rpm);
}
```

It seems like you also have phases: an initialization phase where the user enters values, a run phase, and a finished phase.  You can handle these by using a global "state" variable that keeps track of which phase your in.  You initialize your state in setup(), and then you read it in the loop() to decide what work you need to do.

```
enum { enter_values, run, finish } state;

void setup() {
  // your other initialization goes here
  state = enter_values;  // set up the starting state
}

void loop() {
  switch (state) {
    case enter_values:
      get_values_from_keyboard();
      state = run;
      break;
    case run:
      int rpm = read_rpm_from_sensor();
      adjust_motor_timing(rpm, target_rpm);
      display_speed(rpm);
      if (enough time has elapsed) {
        state = finish;
      }
      break;
    case finish:
      stop_motor();
      // go back to the initial state for the next run
      state = enter_values;
      break;
  }
}
```

That should give you an idea of the general structure.

For some types of sensors and peripheral devices that require very precise timing, you might use interrupts that deal directly with the hardware.  But that's a very similar idea:  you break the work you need to do into very small chunks that you can do over and over again.  The only thing that changes is that the interrupts may literally (briefly) interrupt whatever you were doing.  But the CPU is still doing just one thing at a time.

Comment: I understand your FSM  structure. In a big picture, I can see. So for all the functions, I have to write specific task for the function to work?

Comment: Yes, those were just placeholder functions to give you an idea of the specifics you would have to provide and where they fit into the structure.   
When you implement them, make sure that you don't add any delay calls.  Each step has to finish in a reasonably short amount of time so that the other tasks that are happening "simultaneously" can do what they need to do.